# DAX Running total measure performance problem

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm having performance problem with this total running measure if I try to calculate this for a table with 500.000 rows I got 'out of memory' message.

```
Total purchase = sum(dim_topN_user[sales_amount])

Purchase Running Total = 
VAR MaxRank = Max(dim_topN_user[Rank])
VAR Result = 
            CALCULATE(
                    [Total purchase],
                     dim_topN_user[Rank]<=MaxRank,
                    all(dim_topN_user[Rank]))
RETURN Result
```

I'm a bit puzzled because this pattern is the recommended one from SQLBI. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4gf3eueRD_g

Is there anything I missed here? Do you have any idea how the performance can be improved?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are using this measure in a calculated column on this 500k row table?

Comment: No, I would like to filter this dynamically. That's why I did not calculate it in the source.

Comment: Hmm. If it's dynamic, then I wouldn't expect poor performance (since it doesn't have to do it for every row of the table). I don't see anything wrong with the measure.